# react router: how to prevent value from resetting when switching route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to preserve the value of even when switching page

This is my index.js

```
export default class BasicExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/setting">Setting</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <hr />

          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/setting">
            <Setting />
          </Route>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my setting.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Setting(props) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(6);

  const onlyNumbers = (e) => {
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;

    if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
      setVal(parseInt(e.currentTarget.value));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Test</label>
      <input className="maxcards" value={val} onChange={onlyNumbers} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Setting;
```

**Expected result:** value should not change whenever I switch page

**Actual result:** it is always reset to default valye whenever i switch page

Any advice is appreciated

This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-xb04b?file=/components/Setting.js:0-448)

Comment: local state (usestate) will only live as long as the component is mounted. When using router, it unmounts everything that doesnt match the route. To preserve the state, you would need to either put the state further up the tree (above the routing) as local-state, move it to a context, or use some global-state pattern ala redux.

Comment: what if i create the variable at index.js and call a update function in setting.js? will that work?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Put "const [val, setVal] = useState(6);" in index.js and send setVal as a prop to the "Setting" component like this: "<Setting setVal={setVal} />".

Comment: You may also take a look at React Context depending on the complexity of the state.

The context may hold a "global state" without the need to nest your state within several layers deep of props